# Does logcat dump debug logs while it isn't expressly running?

Tags: reboot, logging

my android device reboots itself automatically sometimes,so i need to get a way to debug whats causing that.

i know about logcat,but what about the debug msgs when logcat isnt running,does logcat gives a dump of logs that android device would be generating while those were not being accessed through logcat?

generally this happens when ur device reboots unexpectedly,and the cause is unknown so that one could replicate it.

how to know of whats causing those reboots.. or anything that happens while logcat isnt running?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Logs are written even when logcat is not connected, although I believe the logs are limited to a certain maximum size. They are, however, cleared on reboot. You can try using an app such as [aLogCat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) to persist the logs to files, and hope it can catch whatever is misbehaving "in the act".

Comment: actually i was using alogcat app. but once my device restarted and upon reboot i quickly restarted alogcat,i saw some red text for fatal error regarding some sql thing.. later i checked the log texts that i set up to auto save.. they didnt had the sql error.. so there is something wrong with that app..